My file with docker-compose commands for make a image and a container with MySQL dont works
I use docker in Windows and make this file
version: '3.9'
services:
  mysql_206:
    container_name: mysql_206
    hostname: mysql_206
    image: mysql:8
    restart: always
    command:
      - --authentication-policy=CACHING_SHA2_PASSWORD
      - --character-set-server=utf8mb4
      - --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
      - --innodb_force_recovery=0
    volumes:
      - ./mysql_206:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: senha
      MYSQL_DATABASE: base_de_dados
      MYSQL_USER: usuario
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: senha
      TZ: America/Sao_Paulo

And when I run the command docker-compose up i recieve this error
mysql_206  | 2024-05-02T17:19:37.530006Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
mysql_206  | 2024-05-02T17:19:37.530047Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
mysql_206  | 2024-05-02T17:19:37.928757Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
mysql_206  | 2024-05-02T17:19:37.928930Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
mysql_206  | 2024-05-02T17:19:37.928955Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
mysql_206  | 2024-05-02T17:19:37.930212Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.4.0)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
mysql_206  | 2024-05-02T17:19:37.930228Z 0 [System] [MY-015016] [Server] MySQL Server - end.
mysql_206 exited with code 1

Thank you very much in advance
In the case of success, normally I should receive a mensage in terminal like this :ready for connections
